# Asterisk Dialplan Phone exten to RegEx

Tags: regex, asterisk

Need to build a RegEx, that came from asterisk dialplan (Brazil Number)

```
valid      = 0021987126408
not valid  = 002198712640
not valid  = 3021987126408
valid      = 0021987126408
```

need to validate asterisk with dialplan => `00ZX[789]XXXXXXXXX`

check in order .....

- check if the two first numbers is ZERO
- check ZX (brazilian DD)
- check (7,8 or 9)
- check if XXXXXXXXX has the same quantity of numbers in the end

basicly transcribe asterisk Dialplan to Normal REGEX.

Comment: @sp00m RegEx =  ^(00\d{2}[7-9]\d{8})$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RegEx =  `^(00\d{2}[7-9]\d{8})$`

```
valid      = 0021987126408
not valid  = 002198712640
not valid  = 3021987126408
valid      = 0021987126408
```